# Opacity not working on IE8

Tags: jquery

This fades the layer in Firefox/Chrome fine - but in IE8 it won't give the layer opacity.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('.out-of-stock').each(function () {
    $('.productImage', $(this)).css('opacity', '.25');
    $('.stockMessage', $(this)).removeClass('stockMessageOff');
    $('.stockMessage', $(this)).addClass('stockMessageOn');
    $('.stockMessage.stockMessageOn', $(this)).css('opacity', '1').text('Sold Out');
  });
});
```

I've read several stackoverflow posts about assigning zoom: 1; to the css class, but that hasn't fixed it.

Any ideas anyone? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained on this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html IE8 (and below) do not support opacity so you have to use the rather clunky code provided by Fabian.

I think an easier option is to simply do what Madmartigan suggests and use jQuery's fadeTo()-method as it will cater for all modern (and not so modern) browsers:

```
$('.productImage').fadeTo(0, .25);
```

I also noticed some things that could be improved in your code. Using only .class selectors is slower than providing the tag name as well as jQuery has to go through EVERY element and match the class instead of just img (for example) elements. You're also not taking advantage of jQuery's ability to chain method calls which not only speeds up a bit but also makes the code tidier:

```
$(function () {
  $('div.out-of-stock').each(function () {
    $('img.productImage', this).css('opacity', '.25');

    $('p.stockMessage', this).removeClass('stockMessageOff').addClass('stockMessageOn').css('opacity', '1').text('Sold Out');
  });
});
```

Just a tip! :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for IE8

```
$('.productImage', $(this)).css('-ms-filter','progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25)');
```

For cross-browser support try to use this:

```
$('.productImage', $(this)).css({'-ms-filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25)','filter':'alpha(opacity=25)','-moz-opacity':'0.25','-khtml-opacity':'0.25','opacity':'0.25'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$('.productImage').fadeTo('fast', .25);
```

Hope it helps.